# When mule-soap exception occurred, how do I send my own fault code and fault string rather than generic soap fault message?

Tags: soap, mule

I am making SOAP call from Mule. I am using default-exception-strategy for catching exception. 
When exception occurred, how do I send my own fault code and fault string rather than generic soap fault message? Thanks

Here is the snippet of mule xml, java code, actual output and expected output

## Mule xml

```
<flow name="addressSearchFlow1" doc:name="addressSearchFlow1">
    <invoke object-ref="InvoiceManager" method="completeSearchObject"
        methodArguments="#[message.payload]"></invoke>

    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />

    <processor-chain doc:name="Search Processor Chain">
        <cxf:jaxws-client operation="doSearch"
            clientClass="com.invoice.web_2007_09.ProWeb" port="InvoicePortType"
            wsdlLocation="proweb.wsdl" enableMuleSoapHeaders="true" doc:name="SOAP">
        </cxf:jaxws-client>
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
            method="POST" ref="InvoiceEndPoint" doc:name="HTTP" />
    </processor-chain>

    <default-exception-strategy>
        <processor-chain>
            <logger message="Exception_logger" level="INFO" doc:name="Exception_logger" />
            <custom-transformer class="com.managers.CustomExceptionHandler" />
            <logger message="Exception_logger" level="INFO" doc:name="Exception_logger" />
        </processor-chain>
    </default-exception-strategy>

</flow>
```

## Java code

```
package com.managers;

import org.mule.api.MuleMessage;
import org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException;
import org.mule.message.ExceptionMessage;
import org.mule.transformer.AbstractMessageTransformer;

public class CustomExceptionHandler extends AbstractMessageTransformer {

public CustomExceptionHandler() {
    setName("CustomExceptionHandler");
}

@Override
public Object transformMessage(MuleMessage message, String outputEncoding)
        throws TransformerException {

    ExceptionMessage exceptionMessage = (ExceptionMessage)message.getPayload();

    String outputMessage = "<soap:Fault xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">        "
            + " <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode> "
            + "<faultstring>"
            + "An unexpected error has occured. Please contact your service desk and quote this error \""  + exceptionMessage.getException() +  "\""+ "</faultstring>      " + "</soap:Fault>";
    return outputMessage;

}

}
```

### Actual output

---

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring> dt-invoice. Failed to route event via endpoint: org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor. Message payload is of type: PostMethod</faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

### Expected output

---

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring> An unexpected error has occured. Please contact your service desk and quote this error   "org.mule.api.transport.DispatchException: dt-invoice. Failed to route event via endpoint: org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor. Message payload is of type: PostMethod"
</faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: I tried looking up the proper Mule doc for the 'invoke'-element. Is it just me, or is there a lack of proper documentation for this element?

Answer (score 1):

You need `<catch-exception-strategy' and not '<default-exception-strategy>` in your flow like this:

```
<flow name="addressSearchFlow1" doc:name="addressSearchFlow1">
    <invoke object-ref="InvoiceManager" method="completeSearchObject"
        methodArguments="#[message.payload]"></invoke>

    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />

    <processor-chain doc:name="Search Processor Chain">
        <cxf:jaxws-client operation="doSearch"
            clientClass="com.invoice.web_2007_09.ProWeb" port="InvoicePortType"
            wsdlLocation="proweb.wsdl" enableMuleSoapHeaders="true" doc:name="SOAP">
        </cxf:jaxws-client>
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
            method="POST" ref="InvoiceEndPoint" doc:name="HTTP" />
    </processor-chain>

    <catch-exception-strategy>
        <processor-chain>
            <logger message="Exception_logger" level="INFO" doc:name="Exception_logger" />
            <custom-transformer class="com.managers.CustomExceptionHandler" />
            <logger message="Exception_logger" level="INFO" doc:name="Exception_logger" />
        </processor-chain>
    </catch-exception-strategy>

</flow>
```

**catch-exception-strategy**: Define a catch exception strategy to customize the way Mule handles any exception. Catch exception strategies consume inbound messages.

**default-exception-strategy**: Defined and implicitly applied by default to handle all messaging exceptions that are thrown in Mule applications

More information is at [mulesoft](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Error+Handling)

Answer (score 1):

Update the flow as below to start using Catch Exception Strategy.

```
<flow name="addressSearchFlow1" doc:name="addressSearchFlow1">
    <invoke object-ref="InvoiceManager" method="completeSearchObject"
        methodArguments="#[message.payload]"></invoke>

    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />

    <processor-chain doc:name="Search Processor Chain">
        <cxf:jaxws-client operation="doSearch"
            clientClass="com.invoice.web_2007_09.ProWeb" port="InvoicePortType"
            wsdlLocation="proweb.wsdl" enableMuleSoapHeaders="true" doc:name="SOAP">
        </cxf:jaxws-client>
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
            method="POST" ref="InvoiceEndPoint" doc:name="HTTP" />
    </processor-chain>

    <catch-exception-strategy>          
        <logger message="Exception_logger" level="INFO" doc:name="Exception_logger" />
        <custom-transformer class="com.managers.CustomExceptionHandler" />
        <logger message="Exception_logger" level="INFO" doc:name="Exception_logger" />          
    </catch-exception-strategy>
</flow>
```

Also in the custom transformer,  the exception is not present in message as payload. it is available in the exceptionPayload.  So use message.getExceptionPayload() which gives you ExceptionPayload as the result. From the exceptionPayload object the exception message and other details can be obtained.

Hope this helps.