# The <invoke>-element of Mule 3, what does it do?

Tags: mule, esb

I have previously only used Mule 2.2.1, but i'm now reading up on Mule 3.4/3.5.

One major change between theses versions is the introduction of flows.

In the [documentation of the Mule configuration](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Understanding+Mule+Configuration) i found this:

> A flow begins with an inbound endpoint from which messages are read and continues with a list of message processors

However, in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18199624/when-mule-soap-exception-occurred-how-do-i-send-my-own-fault-code-and-fault-str) i came across the invoke-element. It appears that a flow can also begin with an invoke-element.

I was searching the Mule documentation for documentation of the invoke element, but was not able to find it. Can someone help explaining the semantics of the invoke-element, or point to any relevant documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "invoke" element is a message processor and not a message source.

The quote "A flow begins with an inbound endpoint from which messages are read and continues with a list of message processors" is not quite true as flows such as sub-flows or private flows that are referenced via other flows using flow-refs do not need an inbound-endpoint and can just have a list of message processors.

So it cannot be used to trigger a flow. However the example above seems to be a private flow which would be referenced from another flow via flow-ref so hence why it starts with a message processor. More eon private and sub-flows here: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Using+Flows+for+Service+Orchestration

Back to the invoke message processor. THere is lacking documentation around this, but simply put, it calls the specified method for the given object using the given arguments.

From the javadoc: invokes a specified method of an object. An array of argument expressions can be provided to map the message to the method arguments. The method used is determined by the method name along with the number of argument expressions provided. The results of the expression evaluations will automatically be transformed where possible to the method argument type. Multiple methods with the same name and same number of arguments are not supported currently - http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/processor/InvokerMessageProcessor.html

Comment: Thanks, thats useful information. I guess Mulesoft should look into documenting that piece of functionality though :-)